# Toggle show/hide div based on paper-toggle-button state

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

Since Polymer 1.0 I can't toggle (show/hide) a div based on the state of a `paper-toggle-button`. This isn't working anymore:

```
<paper-toggle-button checked$="{{_renderBool(prj.ke.manual)}}"
                           on-change="_onManualChanged"></paper-toggle-button>
<div hidden$="{{!prj.ke.manual}}">Test</div>
...
Polymer({
  is: 'test-view',
  properties: {
    prj: {
      type: Object,
      notify: true,
      value: function () { return { }; }
    }
  },
  ready : function () { ... },
  _onManualChanged : function (e) {
    au.projects.current.ke.manual = e.currentTarget.checked;
  },
  ...
  });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

Does anybody has a working example for that?

Answer (score 2):

The right way is to trigger `Polymer` notification system is by using `this.set`. The modification function for the object should be written like this:

```
  _onManualChanged : function (e) {
    this.set('prj.ke.manual', e.currentTarget.checked);
  },
```

Otherwise Polymer didn't recognize the object change!

Answer (score 0):

Change the event function to reference "this" insetead of "au.project.current"

```
_onManualChanged : function (e) {
  this.ke.manual = e.currentTarget.checked;
},
```